# tableView elements limit, UITableView lagging

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tableview

im wondering what is the limit of table View items, currently i'm using around ~120 elements, each element has photo 220x220x, when i exceed around 90-110 table view become a little bit laggy on iPhone 5, i tried to resize photos to 64x64 but, that was still laggy and images quality sucks. Memory usage is low, around 50mb, but when rolling tableview cpu usage jumps 30-90%. Im a little bit worried because i'm going to load ~800 items...

CODE:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cel_f";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Cell* cellF;
    if(self.isFiltered)
        cellF = [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
        cellF = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellF.name;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellF.andThumbImage];
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(295, 11, 25, 21);
    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myLabel.text = @">";
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240 green:248 blue:255 alpha:0.25];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    [cell addSubview:myLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I once had well over 11,000

Comment: with images in each cell? Maybe the problem is in ios8 beta ? I tried on simulator now, tableview works fine, maybe this is a problem, anyway the simulator always have worse performance.

Comment: You should keep in mind that it's not like each cell is stored in memory. Only the visible cells and the cell prototype are stored, the cells are then loaded each time they come into view, so the limit should really be based on the size of your model (the data you put into the cells), not how many cells you have.

Comment: Post the code you use to add images to the cell. Also, to reply directly to a user, prefix their username with an @ sign in the comment. For example, "@duci9y <your comment>".

Comment: @duci9y Im loading cells in cellforRowAtIndexPath, in each cell i have UILabel and image loaded like   cell.imageView.image = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:cellF.andThumbialImage] convertToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)];   I dont think this is because my code, I experienced issue only on device, on simulator working like a charm despite the fact that simulator usually has worse performance.

Comment: Cache those images. You're redrawing at every step.

Comment: In fact, don't redraw at all.

Comment: If you encounter poor scrolling performance the problem is usually not the number of cells in the tableView, but the work you do in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Profile the app with Instrument. If I had to make a guess I would blame your size conversion, it probably works on the CPU and is therefor slow. If you resize from 220x220 to 150x150 it might be better to not resize at all, let the imageView handle this, which should be faster because it runs on the GPU. But without profiling and real code nobody will be able to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch This is not problem caused by my resizing, i tried this code after i noticed that it became laggy, my code looks like i posted now. Any ideas, what im doing wrong? or its ios8 issue?